# how to fetch image from database dynamically in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to fetch image from database my uploading part is working but image not view in home.blade.php

here is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $name=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/storage',$name);
    $photo=new User();
    $photo->image=$name;
    $photo->save();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

my home.blade.php

```
<img class="image rounded-circle"src="{{asset('public/storage/storage'.auth()->user()->image)}}"style="width:150px; height: 150px">
```

my route

```
Route::post('/post','HomeController@store')->name('post');

Route::get('/post','HomeController@create')->name('post');
```

Comment: considering your image is uploaded and a file name is saved inside your database. You can use this to fetch images from Laravel storage: `{{asset('storage/foo') }}`

Comment: still it is not working

Comment: Can you share your image code. Please

Comment: <img class="image rounded-circle" src="{{asset('storage/'.auth()->user()->image)}}"style="width:150px; height: 150px">

Comment: The file should be available at `{{ asset('public/storage/'.auth()->user()->image}}` considering the proper implementation of

Comment: E:\xampp\htdocs\StudentAts\public\storage\storage\user.png this is my image path when i upload image stores here

Comment: Use `{{ asset('storage/storage/'.auth()->user()->image) }}` this will fet h your images

Comment: i also did that but nothing happened